# When using AWS API Gatway and a JWT how do you access JWT in url from lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I have setup an open api on AWS. I can get to it but now want to secure the post method to the API. I have setup cognito as an identity provider and am using a hosted UI. I can launch the hosted UI, login and it goes to my callback (one of my api methods) with a JWT in the url. The problem is that I can not get the token in the url. I have tried dumping the event and context through the lambda as a test and alot of information gets dumped like the host, headers etc but none of the query strings or hash values are visible. The JWT is after the hash. How can I get to those values?

Flow: Browser-> Hosted UI (Authenticate) [success] -> http://...api/signin#access_token

Access_token is not available in the context or event data.